# python - How to speed up screen stream

Tags: python, stream, screen, python-imaging-library

I'm working on a Remote Control program, which can be used in order to allow any PC to control another PC. The controlled PC streaming its screen to the Controller.

My program taking screenshot and send it as jpeg every 1 second. In the Controller PC, it looks preety delayed.

Any suggestions for imporvement?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do some testing to figure out whether the bottleneck was sending the data over your network, or the process of taking the screenshot and preparing the image.

Presuming that it is sending the data over the network, I would suggest sending the full image the first time, and thereafter send diffs. I imagine that a high percentage of the actions that you take by time would be the mouse moving around the screen, so the diffs may often be minimal.

```
from PIL import Image
px1 = im1.load()
px2 = im2.load()
for x in range(0, im1.width):
    for y in range(0, im1.height):
        if px1[x, y] != px2[x, y]:
            ...
```